# DocumentDB Why triggers can not be triggered from Azure portal?

Tags: triggers, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

I have a pre-trigger on replace action. I realized that, unlike SQL Server triggers, the DocumentDB triggers won't fire when you update documents in Azure portal. Do I miss any settings from the portal? or this is how DocumentDB trigger work? only can be triggered from application code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. There is no technical blocker to allow this feature from portal, only that it is currently missing.

It's certainly a valid request to be placed @ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb

Comment: In the meantime, you can use DocumentDBStudio (https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases/tag/0.70) to test triggers

Comment: Thank you! I just posted a request. By the way, one thing I want to make sure is: all the triggers, no matter pre-triggers or post-triggers, they all perform in the same transaction with Create, Delete or Replace actions, right? If anything failed during Create, Delete or Replace, pre-triggers or post-triggers will roll back, right?

Comment: Yes, any failure during CRUD + pre/post triggers will get rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDb Database Triggers are not automatically raised via DML, like create & delete operations, which is common in other databases.

That is, triggers must be specified for each database operation you make in application code. Also, the trigger should be of the same type, that is, an insert operations can only take a create trigger type, not replace type.

Since, I have azure function documentdb output bindings, and don't do the DML operations myself. After wasting a lot time debugging, moved on to create a stored procedure under the database collection, and then called it via Azure function code using below kind of code.

This works perfectly:

```
// call stored procedure, nodejs, azure

'use strict';

var DocumentClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
var client = new DocumentClient(process.env.DB_HOST, {masterKey: process.env.DB_M_KEY});

var sprocLink =
    'dbs/' + sprocDbName1 +
    '/colls/' + sprocCollName1 +
    '/sprocs/' + sprocName1;

var sprocParams = {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2"
};

client
        .executeStoredProcedure(
                sprocLink,
                sprocParams1,
                function (err, results) {

                    if (err) {

                        context.log.error('err');
                        context.log.error(err);

                        return;
                    }

                    context.log.verbose('results');
                    context.log.verbose(results);

                    return;
                });
```

Note: Give values for DB_HOST (url ending with :443/), DB_M_KEY, sprocDbName1 (your db name), sprocCollName1 (your collection name, sprocName1 (your stored proc name)

Before doing above, a stored procedure (sproc) should be created in inside DocumentDb database collection.

Hope that helps.